# Auxillary routing modal getting appended to main component

Tags: angular

Hi everyone i'm trying to display modal dialog using auxiliary routing in angular routing working correctly but modal is not opening instead template is appended at end of the main router.

Here is my code

modal-component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content select="modal-content"></ng-content>
</div>




// actual popup comonent
<app-modal-window>
// some content
</app-modal-window>


// routing configaration
    {
    path: 'product-details/:prodictId',
    component: ProductDetailsComponent,
    outlet: 'modal'
  }
```